# Why does Docker on Linux not allow limiting the number of CPUs?

Tags: docker

Docker on windows has extra settings for cpus limits 
[image: Advaned docker settings]
By default, each container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles is unlimited

From here  https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--kernel-memory-details

But I am not sure in this.
Why then we have that settings in Windows docker?
We don't have something similar to it in linux?

Comment: Are your Windows and Linux host OSes running on the same machine? And are they running the same version of Docker? According to [Limit a container's resources](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu), CPU limits are "Available in Docker 1.13 and higher."

Comment: i have few machines.
Linux containers running under linux-vm on windows on linux docker.
version of docker 17.06.1